# Local function defined with same signature in two cpp files. Why should they be visible to each other?

Tags: c++, uniqueidentifier

Why am I getting an error in Eclipse about having two definitions of the same function:

```
int readPath(const String &destDir, String &pathToFile) {/*Filler*/}
```

One is an old version (or new) that I dropped temporarily to focus on another version. I'd like to keep it in my project directory again.

I can move it but I don't think it's right that identifiers in a cpp file should risk naming collisions with those in other cpp files, unless you are actually `#include`'ing those cpp files, which I'm not.

Comment: Have you tried changing the namespace for the old file? That should eliminate the duplicate method signature.

Comment: If both are linked to the program they will conflict. Unless they are static.

Comment: Yeah put it in an anonymous namespace and you should be fine. It restricts the scope to just that translation unit.

Comment: I'm not using namespaces and as you can see the function is not declared `static`. I'm more concerned with why this should happen than having to rig more code to manage what I have already.

Comment: @rasmus I should learn more about translation units I guess?

Comment: Your problem relates to the fact that you link two compiled translation units that export functions with the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm more concerned with why this should happen

Because that's how C++ (and C) work.

This:

```
int readPath(const String &destDir, String &pathToFile);
```

Is a function declaration. It tells the compiler, "Somewhere in my code, in this translation unit or another, there will exist a function called `readPath`, which takes as arguments ..." That's what you put in header files.

This:

```
int readPath(const String &destDir, String &pathToFile) {/*Filler*/}
```

Is a function *definition*. Definitions don't simply tell the compiler that something "will exist". It tells the compiler that it exists *here*, and here's how it works.

Definitions of namespace-scoped (either in the global namespace or a named one) functions and variables can have two kind of linkage. Definitions with internal linkage means that the definition only counts for that particular translation unit. Code in other translation units cannot directly access functions or variables with internal linkage.

Definitions with external linkage means that *any* translation unit can access the definition directly. All it needs is a way to shut the compiler up. That's what the declaration is for: to tell the compiler "Don't worry: someone else is going to define this for you."

Functions and variables default to *external* linkage. This is by far the most common case. The keyword `static` is used to give functions and variables *internal* linkage.

The one definition rule, with regard to this, requires that functions and variables with external linkage be defined in *exactly once* translation unit within a compiled and linked program. If two translation units *define* the same function, then they violate the one definition rule.

The ODR rule is relaxed when using `inline` functions. These can be defined in multiple translation unit, but only if the implementation is the same for everyone.

> One is an old version (or new) that I dropped temporarily to focus on another version. I'd like to keep it in my project directory again.

Here are your options:

1. Define the functions within an anonymous namespace (a namespace that has no name). By C++ definition, all anonymous namespace have unique names. So it is impossible for symbols defined in two different anonymous namespaces to conflict.
2. #define around the old implementation. Use a #ifdef to essentially switch it off. This is a time-honored technique to keep old code around.
3. Climb out of the dark ages and learn to use *version control*. Old code belongs in previous versions of files, not cluttering up your files now. If you want to find them again, tag those files and revisions.

Comment: Thank you. Thanks three times.

Answer (score 2):

You're breaking the **one definition rule**.

Each translation unit (implementation files + includes) generates an object file. That object file contains all exported symbols. The method, since it is defined in the translation unit, will be exported in both object files. Ergo - the error.

If you **must** have the same function prototype defined differently in multiple implementation files, you can

- add the function to a `namespace` - it can be anonymous if there's no need to give it a name.
- declare it as `static`, thus giving it internal linkage.

Answer (score 1):

You'll still confuse the linker if one symbol ("`readpath`") is available twice.

You can fix this by changing the linkage of one of the two functions from extern to intern (or none) by putting it in an anonymous namespace or declaring it `static`.